# XSD regex: Why is this not working when parsed into HTML with an XSLT?

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xsd

I have an XML file that is "well formed and valid" (matched with an XSD schema, tested at http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/).

I am using these lines of code in the XSD to restrict the XML input of a `<firstname>`:

```
<xsd:pattern value = "[A-Z][a-z]+" />
<xsd:minLength value = "2" />
<xsd:maxLength value = "25" />
```

So, the website mentioned above will throw an error and not validate when the `<firstname>` does not match this regex and length restrictions (say, if I enter "5" as the first name in the XML file).

**But**, when I open the XML file into Firefox (parsed into HTML with an XSL file), it does **not** throw an error and will display whatever is entered into the XML file regardless of the regular expression and length restrictions.

Are XSD schemas not meant to be used in this way, to error check in web browsers? Do I need to use the restrictions in the XSLT instead of the XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 2.0 (and XSLT 2.0) is a strongly-typed language,where all built-in and user-defined schema types can be validated.

**One can use an XSLT 2.0 SA (Schema- oriented) processor to enforce [schema type validation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#stylesheets-and-schemas) of:**

1. A source XML document.
2. The value of any parameter passed to a template/(xsl:)function or (externally) to the stylesheet.
3. The value of any `xsl:variable`.
4. The result produced by any template or xsl:function

**Using these features properly makes unnecessary any post-transformation validation of the transformation result**.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitre! However, browsers do not yet support XSLT 2, am I correct?

Comment: Saxon-CE makes XSLT 2.0 available on all modern browsers. However, it does not support schema-aware processing.

Comment: @IanCampbell: Michael Kay already answered your question. While there won't be XSLT 2.0 SA in the browsers for a while, nothing prevents using a SA XSLT 2.0 processor server-side.

Comment: This is very useful information, thanks @Michael and Dimitre! I am going to start learning Saxon-CE, as not only it is compatible with all browsers and supports XSLT 2.0, but because there is mention of it making HTML5 more readily available. At http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml I see that Saxon-CE "works in any modern browser with JavaScript enabled - including mobile devices"... However, might your average IE user not have Javascript enabled, and not be able to view such pages though?

Comment: @IanCampbell: This is a possibility, and often a web application has two sets of pages -- one for Javascript-enabled browsers, the other (usually cut-down version) for browsers with Javascript disabled.

Comment: I think Javascript is so widely deployed nowadays that a user with Javascript disabled is going to have a rather disappointing web experience. But I imagine there are probably some security-paranoid corporates who insist on configuring their PCs this way.

Answer (score 2):

XSD validation only happens if you request it. Specifying an xsi:schemaLocation doesn't itself consitute a request to perform validation (though there are some tools, e.g. Altova, that interpret it that way).

I'm not actually aware of any XSD validator that works within a browser, but that doesn't mean that none exists.

Comment: Ah ok, so simply specifying an `xsi:schemaLocation` doesn't actually **do** anything... That was confusing me, yes.

Answer (score 1):

- You seem to be using a web browser as an XML validator which it is not.  Web browsers are very forgiving tools because web sites are very diverse and are occasionally breaking all sorts of rules.
- What firefox sees is not the input of the XSL transform, the valid-or-not XML file, but an output of the transform, that is not necessarily valid against any particular schema on your computer.  XSL transform's job is to transform the document into *something else*, in this case XHTML.  Now while there is a schema for validation of XHTML, it most certainly does not have any restriction on first names, so the output of the transform is most likely valid.
- There is a difference between XML well-formedness (meaning that the document *is* XML in terms of paired tags and the like), and validity.  Validity is relative to a particular schema.  That is why you see the phrase "well formed and valid".

The point of this should be, get a validating XML editor for working with XML if it is not HTML.  Browsers can display arbitrary XML, but that's about all.  If you must use a browser and display errors from XSLT, you can do that as follows:

```
<xsl:message terminate='yes'>message here</message>
```

...but that has nothing to do with XSD whatsoever.  That is a different technology.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Jirka. My confusion arised in wondering where the XSD becomes useful in the stages of an XML file being parsed into XHTML. I would imagine then that I should use another language to check if the XML is valid, and if so *then* proceed into parsing it into XHTML via an XSLT...

Comment: Could such a conditional statement of when to use an XSLT be made, or might you have to conditionally create a new XML file with the XSLT import declaration?

Comment: @Ian - Some tools reject non-well-formed inputs, some reject even well-formed but invalid inputs.  However, if you hear no talk of validation, then no XSD validation is usually done.  Re the second comment, yes, you can insert `xsl:terminate` in conditional statements in XSLT.  Those conditional statements would then do the equivalent of validity checking.

Comment: No such instruction as xsl:terminate. And xsl:message is nothing to do with validity checking.

Comment: @Michael, that last comment was a typo but was previously correctly stated as `<xsl:message terminate='yes'>...`. I did find useful information on this at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_message.asp.